# Strange shadow behavior during `alpha` animation

Tags: android, animation, shadow, elevation

Have recycler with `CardView` items. When screen open - I start alpha animation on recycler :

```
recyclerView.animate().alpha(1f).setStartDelay(300).start()
```

Recycler item:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    app:cardElevation="4dp">
...
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Problem that while this animation running the shadow of `CardView` directed to the up but when animation ends shadow change direction to the bottom (as normal)

Problem was found only on Android 9.

P.S. sorry for my english)

Comment: Any update on this? I have the same problem.

Comment: I had the same issue and filed a bug here. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/132569416

Answer (score 1):

I have found a partial fix,

If you add android:layerType="hardware" to the parent view the shadow no longer flips direction.

The down side is the shadow permanently points in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 1):

Found a workaround.
Make sure the alpha-animation targets on CardView itself instead of its parent and its parent's alpha must be 1F.
This work in my case.
Hope it can help you too.