# How to create a more natural CardView alpha animation?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-cardview

I have a normal CardView:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    android:layout_width="256dp"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    app:cardElevation="4dp" />
```

Then I animate its alpha:

```
cardView.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(3000).start()
```

I get:

[image]

The card background first turns grey then white. If time is short, this look like a blink. It seems this only happens on a white background.

This is what I want (I create it in the Adobe XD):

[image]

How can I achieve a similar effect?

Comment: It's because your animation is slow. You will get the exact same in Adobe XD when you reduce the speed of the animation. If you think about it, white with an opacity of 50% = grey...

Comment: @HB. I can't get the exact same in Adobe XD even if I change animation duration to 0.1s. How do you do it? I don't think 50% opacity white == grey. They're two different colors.

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The grey you are seeing is the shadow of your `CardView`.

You can add the `CardView` inside another view and animate that view instead, for example:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/animateThis"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="256dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        app:cardElevation="4dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then animate the `RelativeLayout` instead:

```
animateThis.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(3000).start()
```

Comment: This works! But we get another problem like this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54646927/strange-shadow-behavior-during-alpha-animation but that seems CardView's problem.

Comment: @DeweyReed looking at the issue tracker, it seems to be an issue with `CardView`. You can star that post to get the issue resolved quicker.

Answer (score 2):

Just to share a different approach. I hope it may help others.

I have created an animation that changes alpha and elevation sequentially, to avoid showing the shadow while animating alpha.

For fade in I use:

```
<set android:ordering="sequentially">
        <objectAnimator
            android:duration="300"
            android:propertyName="alpha"
            android:valueTo="1"
            android:valueType="floatType" />
        <objectAnimator
            android:duration="300"
            android:propertyName="cardElevation"
            android:valueTo="12dp"
            android:valueType="floatType" />
    </set>
```

For fade out I use:

```
<set android:ordering="sequentially">
        <objectAnimator
            android:duration="300"
            android:propertyName="cardElevation"
            android:valueTo="0dp"
            android:valueType="floatType" />
        <objectAnimator
            android:duration="300"
            android:propertyName="alpha"
            android:valueTo="0"
            android:valueType="floatType" />
    </set>
```

Answer (score 0):

fadein.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true" >

    <alpha
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:toAlpha="1.0" />

</set>

 Animation animFadein = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
                R.anim.fade_in);
        cardView.startAnimation(animFadein);
```

Comment: Try this. I have just tested it. It works the way you wanted. You can change android:fromAlpha based on your requirement. 0.0f to 1.0f

Comment: I can't make it work with this solution and still get the grey at the beginning. How did you do it?

Comment: There is a difference here. It is android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator" which makes it smooth. You have to make Card elevation and translation to 0dp.

Comment: I get you but I need the elevation. That's why I use a CardView. As long as I add 1dp elevation, the grey is shown.

Comment: Try using translationZ instead of elevation

Comment: translationZ still doesn't help. BTW, the accepted answer works.